# calling model dynamically in go

Tags: go, dynamic, struct, model, go-gorm

Consider products like jeans, shirts, shorts and I want to store the orders in respective product tables for eg jeans related order should get stored in jeans tables and so on. Every table would have identical parameters. So while storing orders in table I should be able to call the respective struct and store the order.
I am coming from Laravel (PHP) background where I can load dynamic model like

```
$model = "Dynamic passed model names"

$class = "App\\Models\\$model";
```

but in Go how can we do that if call dynamic struct

e.g,

in model ABC.go

```
type ABC struct{
  Name string
  Invetory int
}
```

in model XYZ.go

```
type XYZ struct {
  Name string
  Invetory int
}
```

So input could be ABC or XYZ and I have to load the struct accordingly.

load the struct ABC

```
inpt := "ABC"

product := models.<inpt>{
  Name: "prodct name"
  Inventory: 10
}
```

Above snippet the model name is dynamic. How can we do this in Go?

Comment: I literally never had a point where I had to load a struct dynamically. Out of cusriosity - what is the use case here.

Comment: If your product tables are identical, then they should probably be a single table, with a `product` column.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, To reduce the load on tables. Basically, we are distributing the data in different (respective) tables.

Answer (score 2):

Do not try to port methods and programming patterns from other languages to Go - it will make your life harder at best and will end in tears at worst.

You can do something like:

```
type Inventory interface{
 // Your interface defining methods here
}

var toUse Inventory

switch input {
case "ABC":
   toUse = ABC{}
case "XY":
   toUse = XY{}
}
```

The question is why you have two ***types*** which are (aside from a typo) exactly identical.

Comment: There could be n number of models, I cannot keep adding cases for every model.

Comment: @AmitSharma Again - your architecture seems flawed. I literally never had to dynamically load a data model in roughly 30 years of programming, much less an arbitrary number. „I cannot“ seems to be more of a „I do not want to“, tbh. As far as I can see, your question is more of a „Is Go a drop in replacement for Laravell, but with just a few cool features added?“ The answer is no.

Comment: I have some scenarios here, currently, I am working on a cryptocurrency exchange platform where users can trade on our platform against various pairs like BTC_USDT, BTC_BNB, BTC_LTC and so on,.So to reduce the database load we thought, we should store the trade orders in the respective crypto pair table. Like BTC_USDT related orders in tbl_btc_usdt and so on. I don't want to create separate APIs for every pair's order instead use single API endpoint and dynamically call the table struct.

Comment: @AmitSharma How about making the currency a freaking value? `type Exchange struct { type ExchangeType, currency Currency, amount float}` where ExchangeType can be either a put or a call, currency is a [iota „enum“](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Iota) and you end with a single data model for all currencies?

Comment: @AmitSharma: What you are describing is not N models, it's exactly 1 model, with N instances.

Comment: @Flimzy To reduce the load on tables, basically, we are distributing the data in respective tables. That's why we are using N models architecture

Comment: @AmitSharma do those N tables have all the same structure? i.e. do all of them have the same columns? If so, why can't those N tables be represented by single Go struct? How does having N identical struct types declared in Go reduce the load on a database?

Comment: @AmitSharma: No, you still have only a single model. You just have it spread over multiple tables.

Comment: @AmitSharma And tables do not have a load. A DBMS has. Actually, by using more tables, which all have metadata and stuff, you increase the load you put on your DBMS (at least RAMwise, if not even I/O-wise and CPU-wise). As Flimzy said, you have one model with various instances.

Comment: to split your load onto many tables, use a single model with a TableName parameter. With your orm, or whatever, make sure to run sql queries against the TableName parameter. When you instantiate the model, you identify the TableName dynamically.

Comment: @mh-cbon Sounds like a way to do it. But still the question is why should one? It adds a layer of complexity to prevent the usage of what clearly is a field.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg say your dbms engine does not handle row locking, doing so you can split the cost of table locks. I did not intend to mean this is a good idea, only to provide a mean to implement that in a simple solution.

Comment: @mh-cbon I see. Still feels like the famous premature optimization, which - as we all know since Donald Knuth - is the root of all evil.

Comment: @mkopriva, Yes, I have a single model, but multiple-instance or tables. So according to the input I want to insert into a respective table that's my requirement.