# How to pass dynamic table name in gorm model

Tags: mysql, go, model, go-gorm

I am using **Gorm** ORM for my current application. I have one model correspondents to many tables with identical table structures(i.e. column name and type). So my requirement how can I change the table name dynamically while doing the query.

For e.g.

I have product model like Product.go

```
type Product struct{
  ID int
  Name strig
  Quantity int
}
```

And we have different products like shirts, jeans and so on and we have same tables like shirts, jeans.

Now I wanted to query the product as per name of the product how can we do that also  want to have table created through migrations. But there is only One model than how can we run use Automigrate feature with Gorm.

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58889672/calling-model-dynamically-in-go/58889925 ? in gorm you can do queries like `db.Table("users").Select("COALESCE(age,?)", 42).Rows()` or `db.Table("users").Select("COALESCE(age,?)", 42).Find(&users)`etc

Comment: Do we have something like 
prod := models.Product{table: "shirts"}
db.prod.Select("COALESCE(age,?)", 42).Rows()

Comment: have you read the doc ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Updated for GORM v2**

DEPRECATED: `TableName` will not allow dynamic table name anymore, its result will be cached for future uses.

There is a much easier way to create several tables using the same struct:

```golang
// Create table `shirts` & `jeans` with the same fields as in struct Product
db.Table("shirts").AutoMigrate(&Product{})
db.Table("jeans").AutoMigrate(&Product{})

// Query data from those tables
var shirts []Product
var jeans []Product
db.Table("shirts").Find(&shirts)
db.Table("jeans").Where("quantity > 0").Find(&shirts)
```

But, now on the second thought, I would suggest using the embedded struct so that you won't have to call `Table` in every query and you can also have additional fields per model while still sharing the same table structure.

```golang
type ProductBase struct {
  ID int
  Name strig
  Quantity int
}

type Shirt struct {
  ProductBase
  NeckType string
}

type Jean struct {
  ProductBase
  Ripped bool
}

db.AutoMigrate(&Shirt{}, &Jean{})

shirt, jeans := Shirt{}, make([]Jean, 0)
db.Where("neck_type = ?", "Mandarin Collar").Last(&shirt)
db.Where("ripped").Find(&jeans)
```

**Old answer for GORM v1**

You're almost there by using `table` field inside the struct:

```golang
type Product struct{
  ID int
  Name strig
  Quantity int

  // private field, ignored from gorm
  table string `gorm:"-"`
}

func (p Product) TableName() string {
  // double check here, make sure the table does exist!!
  if p.table != "" {
    return p.table
  }
  return "products" // default table name
}

// for the AutoMigrate
db.AutoMigrate(&Product{table: "jeans"}, &Product{table: "skirts"}, &Product{})

// to do the query
prod := Product{table: "jeans"}
db.Where("quantity > 0").First(&prod)
```

Unfortunately, that does not work with `db.Find()` when you need to query for multiple records... The workaround is to specify your table before doing the query

```golang
prods := []*Product{}
db.Table("jeans").Where("quantity > 0").Find(&prods)
```

Comment: It will not work properly. You are setting the default table name that actually will be returned. See underlying implementation of ParseWithSpecialTableName function.
Gorm creates new value base on its type reflect.New(modelType).
What you can do to bypass it is to set db.Statement.Table.
e.g

db.Statement.Table = SomeModel.TableName()
and then execute
db.AutoMigrate((*SomeModel)(nil))

Comment: @AndriiSoluk thanks for your comment. The old answer was meant for gorm v1 instead... I've updated it for v2 with a new tip ;)

Comment: Just wanted to add a quick comment on the v2 answer, creating tables by name and embedding structs solve two different problems. You can most definitely have one struct and need different table names.